# WKWebView checking for HTML form submission

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift4, wkwebview

I have been tasked with converting an Objective-C app to fully Swift 4. The app is basically a webbroswer that wraps my companies website. To keep the users form complaining about entering their username / password each time, the app needs to check when an HTML form was submitted and scrape the site and store the u/p.

In ObjC there was a method:
`- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`

That allowed me to check when a form was submitted:

```
static NSString * const FORM_USER = @"document.getElementById('sUserID').value";
static NSString * const FORM_PASS = @"document.getElementById('sPassword').value";

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

        //save form data
        if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //grab the data from the page
                NSString *username = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: FORM_USER];
                NSString *password = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: FORM_PASS];

                //store values locally in the background
                //.....
            });

        }
        return true;
    }
```

But I am having trouble converting that Swift 4.1 as I can't seem to find any type of `UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted` for WKWebView.

**Any help?**

```
let FORM_USER = "document.getElementById('sUserID').value"
let FORM_PASS = "document.getElementById('sPassword').value"

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation) {

    if(webView.url == API_LOGIN_URL){

        if(WHAT A DO I CHECK FOR here?){

            //Grab IN LOGIN DETAILS
            var name = webView.evaluateJavaScript("\(FORM_USER)", completionHandler: nil)
            var pass = webView.evaluateJavaScript("\(FORM_PASS)", completionHandler: nil)

            //store values locally
            //...
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.formSubmitted
```

or

```
if navigationType == .formSubmitted
```